# groovy plugin for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy, eclipse-plugin

what is the best goovy plugin for eclipse (helios)? I have download [Groovy-Eclipse](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki) but the plug-in seems not good? cant go to methods by clicking ctrl and also cant debug too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best Eclipse Groovy/Grails support is provided by the [STS](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) Eclipse distribution. If you're not using Grails and are only interested in Groovy I don't think you'll find this much better than the Groovy-Eclipse plugin, because I expect STS itself uses the Groovy-Eclipse plugin.

The best Groovy/Grails support is provided by IntelliJ. Eclipse has always been a long way behind.

Comment: NetBeans also has decent Groovy and Grails support, but I would also agree that IntelliJ has the best support for both Groovy and Grails.

Comment: Unfortunately Pivotal have dropped support for Groovy and Grails in early 2015.  I gather Groovy and Grails development will continue elsewhere despite this, but GGTS development may not. See this page on [spring.io](https://spring.io/tools/ggts) and this post on the [Pivotal site](http://blog.pivotal.io/pivotal/news/groovy-2-4-and-grails-3-0-to-be-last-major-releases-under-pivotal-sponsorship#comment-709292)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, groovy-eclipse is the best there is.
If you want to improve your experience, I can only recommend switching to IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 1):

Groovy-Eclipse is your only option for editing groovy code in Eclipse.

Since the behavior you describe that is missing is a fundamental part of Groovy-Eclipse (ie- navigation to method declarations), it sounds like something is not set-up properly in your project.  Perhaps your groovy sources are not on the Eclipse build path of your project.  Make sure this is the case and let me know if this fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since SpringSource / VMWare embraced the Grails and Groovy community, SpringSource Toolsuite (STS) has really increased the quality and integration of Groovy into the Eclipse environment.  If you haven't looked at it recently, STS 2.7.0 was just released, and it includes support for Gradle, Groovy 1.8, and initial support for Grails 1.4 / 2.0.  Groovy-Eclipse is the bundled Groovy solution, and enables the Groovy compiler, Groovy project types, as well as a number of other areas.

It's also important to note that the development is going at a pretty good place - some of the standard editing features are fixed month to month as dot releases are released often.

Intellij is also continuing to provide a great solution - but now that the Eclipse support is improving, there are two viable choices for developers to look at.

STS is available for Eclipse 3.6 and 3.7.

Comment: SpringSource may have improved Groovy/Grails development in Eclipse considerably, but it's still a **long** way behind IntelliJ

Comment: I agree IntelliJ is a well polished and excellent platform -- my point was that STS is now usable for day to day development activities.  We started using it ~2.5.0, which still had a number of gotchas in groovy/grails, 2.6 was much more usable, and 2.7 is further along then that.  For those that can't afford the ultimate intellij for grails, STS is good for day to day developers and most of the headaches are gone now.